# Как найти минимальное из 3 чисел за 2 сравнения?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сравнение

Даны a, b, c. Как найти минимум из них за два сравнения?

Comment: `d = ((a > b)? b : a); result = (d > c)? c : d;`

Comment: result = min( min(a,b), c ) . Каждый вызов min - одно сравнение.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но у меня получилось читабельнее))

if (a < b){
    min = a;
}else{
    min = b;
}

if (min > c){
    min = c;
}

Answer (score 1):

спасибо за помощь, но у меня получилось читабельнее))

```
if (a < b){
    min = a;
}else{
    min = b;
}

if (min > c){
    min = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно совсем без сравнений:

```
private static int Min (int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b - Math.abs(a - b)) / 2;
}

Min(Min(a, b), c);
```

Comment: `Math.abs` работает без сравнений?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в исходниках java - [нет](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l1346), но вообще можно и [без сравнений](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs).

Comment: Ну тогда либо берите сразу библиотечную `Math.min()`, либо пишите полностью свой вариант без использования сравнений, иначе в чем смысл?

Comment: это задание для логики, а в случае использование таких функции это не считается)